# Dynamically stripping objects from their fields in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have two Collections, for some `objects` and `parents`:

```
Objects = new Meteor.Collection('objects');
Parents = new Meteor.Collection('parents');
```

The objects contain some fields and refer to a parent object, for example:

```
Objects.insert({ name: "o1", parent: "p1", f1: "val1", f2: "val2", f3: "val3" });
Objects.insert({ name: "o2", parent: "p2", f1: "val4", f2: "val5", f3: "val6" });
```

The parents define which field can be sent to the client, for example:

```
Parents.insert({ name: "p1", allowedFields: [ "name", "f1", "f2" ] });
Parents.insert({ name: "p2", allowedFields: [ "name", "f1", "f3" ] });
```

I want to publish/subscribe to all objects, but receive them stripped of their non-allowed fields.

According to the above example, I'm expecting the following on the client:

```
{ name: "o1", f1: "val1", f2: "val2" });
{ name: "o2", f1: "val4", f3: "val6" });
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Context:

- Meteor
- I will typically have 100 `parents` and 1000 `objects`
- I don't know in advance how many `parents`/`objects` I will have, and don't know what allowed fields will be referred to by each `parent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following...

On the server:

```
Meteor.publish('objects', function(parentName) {
    var parent = Parents.findOne({'name': parentName});
    var allowedFields = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.allowedFields; i++)
        allowedFields[parent.allowedFields[i]] = 1;
    return Objects.find({ parent: parentId}, { fields: allowedFields });
});
```

On the client:

```
Parents.find({}).foreach(function(parent) {
    Meteor.subscribe('objects', parent.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [field specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers) to limit the fields passed from the server to the client. This should be the simplest method to do so.

For example:

```
Objects.find({},
    {fields: {name:1, f1:1, f2:1}});
```

In this scenario, the fields line permits the 'name', 'f1', and 'f2' fields to be passed-on to the client.